# Partial refund with PayPal Refund API for adaptive payments returns Internal Error (520002)

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to write code to do partial refunds for adaptive payments.

I've read though https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Refund_API_Operation/

and this is what my request looks like

```
curl -s --insecure
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: api_username" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: api_password" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: api_signature" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV"
-H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: your_app_id "          
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Refund  -d  
"requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US 
&requestEnvelope.detailLevel=ReturnAll
&transactionId=xxxxxxxxxx
&currencyCode=USD
&receiverList.receiver(0).amount=10.00"
```

The original transaction has amount > 10.00 and I am trying to partially refund this payment

The response is just basically 'Internal Error' with error code 520002

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

figured this out. basically I also have to specify
`receiverList.receiver(0).email` in my request

The crazy thing is, in PayPal's documentation, it clearly says

`receiverList.receiver(n).email` is `The identified receiver's email address`
`receiverList.receiver(n).amount` is `Amount to refund to the identified receiver`

since I am partially refunding to user, the email should be user's email, right?

Wrong, the email must be my PayPal's account email instead

Don't ask me why and if you can make sense from this madness, please let me know.

PS. thanks PayPal, for returning a very useful error called `internal error`

Comment: the whole paypal system is overly complex, poorly documented and sometimes getting close to madness. It's one of the greatest mysteries that they're still leaders in the field. Anyway thanks, the answer was useful.